# Logged In session and want to create new table details with the UserName as the Primary Key in Asp.Net C SHarp

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql

I have created a website and there are 2 database tables. 1 containing about all the UserDetails and the other is containing all the ItemDetails. Now the only common thing is UserName as  whenever i get logged in i used this code to get the Username in my logged in page

```
Session["New"]=UserNameText.Text;
```

This will contain only username after when my log in is complete. Now I have one more table and its attributes are Uname (Primary Key) - In order to store detail for that specific user Name only. So the Add Item page is currently using ItemDetails table where person will basically enter details about Item and as soon as they this Submit Button , a new Query runs and stores the new details but i want to add this UserNameText.Text from other page in order to use uName column as the same one of the userDetails Table.

How could i use the table afterwards for editing and deleting using Grid View and show only the specific logged in User about their Items only for updation and deletion?

I tried to use gridview but it shows all the details from all the  Usernames

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I found it a bit difficult to understand your question, so try to keep your question short and direct to make it easier to read. You can edit your question to clarify, and you can also use markup to highlight code etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an SqlDataSource with a username parameter, and set the parameter in the page load.

Example:

In code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Session["New"];
    sqlSummary.SelectParameters["username"].DefaultValue = username;
}
```

In your ASPX:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlSummary" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MyTable] 
                    WHERE ([username] = @username)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="--" Name="username" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="gvSummary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataSourceID="sqlSummary" AllowPaging="True">
</asp:GridView>
```